# ListPlot vector 3D circle line

Tags: plotting, vector

I got a 2D vector with the following code.

```
lx = N[Table[{{r Cos[phi], r Sin[phi] }, { -Sin[phi], Cos[phi]}}, {r, 
     0.5, 2, 0.5}, {phi, 0, 2 \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/(10 (r + 0.1))}]];
ListVectorPlot[lx, VectorPoints -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 1

I would like to plot a similar 3D vector, where the vectors is distributed around a circle. I tried `VectorPlot3D`, but I get the 3D vector with square lattice, which is not what I expect.
I want the 3D vectors are arranged on a circle line, similar to the 2D vectors. Thanks for any suggestion.

[image]

Figure 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Graphics3D` combined with `Arrow`. 
If you want to change colors, just modify the value of nn.

```
nn=1;    
dx = 0.5;
    tab = Table[
       Flatten[Table[
         Arrow[{{c Cos[x] Sin[y], c Sin[x] Sin[y], 
            c Cos[y]}, {c Cos[x + dx] Sin[y], c Sin[x + dx] Sin[y], 
            c Cos[y]}}], {x, 0, 2 Pi, dx}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, dx}], 1], {c, 1, 
        3, 1}];
    Graphics3D[Table[{Hue[nn/i], tab[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[tab]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would be nice if the color of the arrow can be determined by the value of r.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `SliceVectorPlot3D`

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {Norm[{x, y, z}, 2] == 2.5}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, VectorPoints -> 7, 
 VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]